# To normalize or not to normalize for few distinct values

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization, dimensional-modeling

Assuming in a Postgres database, you have a table called `party`, which can have less than 5 well-defined `party_types` such as 'Person' or 'Organization'.

Would you store the `party_type` in the `party` table (e.g. `party_type = 'Person'`) or normalize it (e.g. `party.party_type = 1` and `party_type(id, name) = (1, 'Person')`)?
And why?

Comment: I wouldn't normalize that unless it's for a datawarehouse with large amounts of data where the bits saved can sum up to significant amounts of space. So my answer is "depends" :)

Comment: I wouldn't call that normalization by the way.

Comment: @ypercube can you please explain?

Comment: Adding a surrogate key column has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @ypercube you mean the case when there is a FK defined on `party_type`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are implementing party-role-relationship model or part of it, having `party_type` as a separate entity is very important. You may have many more tables with foreign key to party_type (for instance, to limit applicability of certain roles to particular party type[s], or to enforce relationships between different types of parties, etc).  Using check constraints in any form (including enums) in such cases would hide the logic and make maintenance harder .

Comment: A bit off topic, is a `party_type` table a good way to create two subtypes of `party` (as opposed to create two separate entities / tables `person` and `organization`)?

Comment: I guess you meant `party` table, not `party_type` which will be a small lookup. Depends on other requirements, you may store organization and person in one table ; that seems ok to me under some circumstances .

Answer (score 5):

I would use an [`enum` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) for that.

Comment: +1 For an entity without any further attributes, an `enum` type is like a poor man's lookup table and may pass as "normalized".

Answer (score 0):

I always use a lookup table since your app may expand ("Organization" may become "Retail organization" once you add "Institutional organization" for example). A single location for the type name is great when you realize the type is slightly more specific or different than the original name would imply. Also, this is a great place to add values specific to the type like "CanHaveMultipleLogins" which VERY often get hard coded.